# Vue.js dynamic dropdown

Tags: javascript, dynamic, vue.js

How would I make a dynamic dropdown in vue, not sure what I am doing wrong.

in my html I have...

```
<div id="app">
     <select v-model="selected">
             <option disabled value="">Please select one</option>
             <option v-for="item in selected"></option>
     </select>
```

and my js looks like....

```
new Vue({
        el: '#app',
        data: {
          selected: ["Apache", "Cochise"],
        }
      })
```

filters looks like this
[image]

EDIT:
the values appear in the html DOM tree in the inspector
[image]

but not in the dropdown
[image]

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Try this.

```
new Vue({
    el: '#app',
    data: {
        filters: filters,
        selectedValue: null
    }
})

<div id="app">
     <select v-model="selectedValue">
         <option disabled value="">Please select one</option>
         <option v-for="item in filters" :value="item">{{item}}</option>
     </select>
</div>
```

[Example](http://codepen.io/Kradek/pen/ryRyPX?editors=1010).

**Note**: For future readers, there was also an issue where the normal delimiters for [text interpolation needed to be customized](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/api/#delimiters) in @captnvitman's evnironment.

Comment: that work mostly, except for the options do not show in the dropdown, I edited my question with pictures to show what I mean

Comment: @captnvitman where does `filters` come from? And can you link where you are seeing this? It works in the example.

Comment: @captnvitman possibly a version issue? I am using Vue 2 in the example.

Comment: from an ajax call, however I changed it to filters: ['Apache','Cochise'] like in your example to keep it simple. I'll edit my question to reflect that

Comment: I switched to the same version to check, still the same problem. perhaps its another library im using like bootstrap that is messing with it

Comment: @captnvitman It looks like you forgot to add `{{item}}` inside the `<option></option>`. If you look at your screenshot, there is a `value` but no text.

Comment: i have it like this <option v-for="item in filters" :value="item">{{item}}</option> ... still no luck

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/139808/discussion-between-bert-evans-and-captnvitman).

Comment: for anyone looking at this in the future with the same problem, it was a problem with the delimiters (maybe getting confused with the django templating?) set delimiters: ['${', '}'], in new Vue () and use ${} for vue templating. thanks to @Bert Evans